# encode() Geohash of dataframe generates 'Invalid argument', but how?

Tags: pandas, geohashing

`import Geohash as gh`

`gh.encode(35., -100., 7)` works great!

`df.apply(lambda x: x.latitude*x.longitude, axis=1)` also works great.

But

`df.apply(lambda x: gh.encode(x.latitude, x.longitude, precision=7), axis=1)`

should work, but instead it generates a 'Invalid argument' error. But for the life of me I don't see why!

Comment: I found a NAN buried in the df. Shoulda known.